# how can I detect a domain name (ex: .com , .org etc) in a textarea and show that domain as a url using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am new in JQuery. I am having problem to detect a domain name (ex: www.google.com , rubyonrails.org etc) in a textarea(where there may be normal texts existing) and only show that domain name as a hyperlink when viewing the whole text in another page.

Comment: You can't put elements (like links) in a textarea. You'll have to use some sort of superimposition or use an editable div.

Comment: Your question is completely unclear, please add more information to it what do you want to do.

Comment: I think you need to get the text from textbox and use regex expression to determine whether a word is part of domain or not.  Also i could not understand why you get a -1 rating. Your question seems logical.

Comment: why would you need to do this with jQuery instead of parsing the text at server?

Comment: Suppose, I write a text in the text area "Please visit www.google.com" and I want to view this text where "Please visit" will be shown as normal text and "www.google.com" will show as a hyperlink. If I click that link I will be redirected to "www.google.com".
I think this will make my question more clear 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will find the domain from a String. You can use this code on some event in text area and then use the matched String as href of a  tag.

```
var str = "This is text string. Here comes the domain http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_regexp.asp Its another Test String.";
var pattern = /((?:(?:http|ftp):\/\/)[^ ]*)/gi;
console.log(str.match(pattern));
```